# Reactjs - Cannot POST /images error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have problem in reactjs, when i upload the image in reactjs with react-images-uploader then I am getting error

> "Cannot POST /images error"

Here is the code of Image upload code:

```
<ImagesUploader
        url="/images"
        optimisticPreviews
        onLoadEnd={(err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        }}
        label="Upload multiple images"
        />
```

***error image***

[image]

Comment: what is your backend, and have you set it up to support POST requests at that endpoint ?

Comment: I am just uploading in reactjs images folder. and I used axios package.

Comment: You need to be using a server to be able to upload, and you need to set it up to support post requests at `/images`. See example at https://github.com/aleksei0807/react-images-uploader#example-server-nodejs-express (for node.js/express)

Comment: I can not upload it local server?

Comment: Yes, but you still need to set it up correctly. Are you using a local server that you setup or the one provided by react-create-app

Comment: Yes and all are working fine, only I am unable to upload the image. if you will help then it will be great thing.

Answer (score 0):

use the full path for API endpoint, not only /images,

http://myapi.loc/images

Comment: is your server is up and running? and /images endpoint exist?

Comment: I am running at localhost.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172819/discussion-between-ajay-m-and-narek-hakobyan).